# How do I get raw bitmap data onto the screen under OS X using Apple Swift?

Tags: swift, graphics

I am converting my old software 3D engine into Swift (for fun, ha ha) and my minimal knowledge of OS X programming has tripped me up.  I've written an entire 3D engine with no trouble, but getting the rendered frames onto the screen is beyond me.  Assume I know NOTHING of OS X.  What is the simplest method to make a window (even fixed size) and blit data to it repeatedly?  This is as far as I have got:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
let width = 640
let height = 480
let image = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
    pixelsWide: width,
    pixelsHigh: height,
    bitsPerSample: 8,
    samplesPerPixel: 3,
    hasAlpha: false,
    isPlanar: false,
    colorSpaceName: NSDeviceRGBColorSpace,
    bytesPerRow: 4 * width,
    bitsPerPixel: 32)
var bitmapData: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = image.bitmapData

// INSERT 3D ENGINE HERE

let application = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
application.setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular)
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 640, 480), styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask, backing: .Buffered, defer: false)
window.center()
window.title = "Silly 3D Engine"
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
class WindowDelegate: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate {
    func windowWillClose(notification: NSNotification?) { NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(0) }
}
let windowDelegate = WindowDelegate()
window.delegate = windowDelegate
class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var _window: NSWindow
    init(window: NSWindow) { self._window = window }
}
let applicationDelegate = ApplicationDelegate(window: window)
application.delegate = applicationDelegate
application.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
application.run()
```

That was lifted from a couple of places, but it basically gives me a pointer to some raw data, and a window the right size.  The bit I'm missing is how / where I can add some lines to get the bitmap into the window.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but the `CGImage` type may help: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely part of the puzzle.  From experience on other systems I'm expecting to then do something like `func redraw() { var context = getDrawingContext(); context.renderImage( 0, 0, myNiceNSImageOrGDImageObject ); }` etc.